# Hangman game comparing the letter the user selected with the letters in the word to be guesses

Tags: javascript

This is a simple hangman game i made an alphabet keyboard by buttons so onclick  it should call the function checkLetter to 
check if the letter selected in the word to be guessed or not this part it doesn't run also how to delete the letter on the button when the user clicked on it so prevent him select it again?!
this is my code
begin with html 
then javascript

```js
    var B
    ,L
    ,placeholder 
    ,correctGuesses
    ,wrongGuesses
    ,wordToGuess
    ,wordLength
    ,words=[]
    ,wrongletter=true;

    function newGame()
    {
      //initialize all the variables
      placeholder="";
      correctGuesses=0;
      wrongGuesses=0;
      wordToGuess=getWord();
      wordLength=wordToGuess.length;
      
      //make a loop that replaces underscores with the word to be guessed
      for(var i=0;i<wordLength;i++)
      {
       placeholder+="_ ";
      }
       document.getElementById("placeforword").innerHTML=placeholder;
      
      //loop to make a keyboard of buttons 
      //B hold the buttons
     B = '';
    //L hold letters
     L;
    //this loop to get the letters by charcode
    for (var i = 65; 90 >= i; i++) {// A-65, Z-90
      L = String.fromCharCode(i);
      B += '<button id="B2" onclick="getLetter(\''+L+'\');">' + L + '</button>';
    }
    document.getElementById("box1").innerHTML = B;
    drawCanvas();
    }
    function getLetter(x)
    {
       checkLetter(x);
    }
    function checkLetter(letter)
    {
     document.getElementById("placeforword").innerHTML=placeholder;
        placeholder=placeholder.split(""); 
              for(var i=0;i<wordLength;i++)
          { 
           if(wordToGuess.charAt(i)===letter.toLowerCase())
           {
               placeholder[i]=letter;
               wrongletter=false;
               correctGuesses++;
           }
           if(correctGuesses===wordLength)
           {
            //if all letters have been guessed that mean u guessed all the correct letters and u win
            //call the drawCanvas
            drawCanvas();
    
           }
          }
           //if ur guess was wrong
     if(wrongGuess)
     {
      badGuesses++;
      drawCanvas();//this function to draw the body of the victim
     } 
     document.getElementById("placeforword").innerHTML=placeholder.join("");
      
    }
function getWord()
{
 var a=["bad","happy","anyotherwords"];
 //choose a random word
 return a[parseInt(Math.random()*a.length)];
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>New Game</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    #B1 {
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: white;
      font-size: 24px;
    }
    #box2 {
      width: 350px;
      height: 350px;
      padding: 10px;
      background-color: blue;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container" style="width:100%;">
    <div id="left" style="float:left;width:50%;">
      <div id="newgame">
        <button onclick="newGame()" id="B1">New Game</button>
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>
      <!--<div id="newgame1"></div>-->
      <div id="box1"></div>
      <div>
        <p id="placeforword"></p>
      </div>
      <div id="box2">
        <h1>Letters u Guessed</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="right" style="float:right;width:50%;">
      <div>
        <canvas id="stage" width="643" height="643" style="border:5px solid #000000;"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please use punctuation. I understand that English is not the first language of many users, but your question is almost unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

Your button id should be unique. So change the for loop that creates the button to

```
for (var i = 65; 90 >= i; i++) {// A-65, Z-90
  L = String.fromCharCode(i);
  B += '<button id="'+L+'" onclick="getLetter(\''+L+'\');">' + L + '</button>';
}
```

And in getLetter() function you can disable the button,

```
function getLetter(x)
{
   checkLetter(x);
   document.getElementById(x).disabled = true;
}
```

Comment: It didn't work ,only one letter is replaced with underscore and the button didn't disable

Comment: There has been small error in my code with the `'` mark, on `<button id="'+L+'"`. Check now

Comment: But I can't get your code work. I think there is some other error

Comment: plz look at the function checkLetter() ,is somthing wrong?!!

Comment: @emma Reworked with your code. Check my other answer and let me know if that helps

Comment: @emma Checking what ?

Comment: i mean the replacing

Comment: if the  selected letter  is in the word we replace the underscore with that letter ,it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Reworked with your code. The changes are commented on the snippet itself.

My comments are placed between `/////////` and `\\\\\\\\\\\` for easy understanding.

The `drawCanvas()` function has been commented out because it is not defined.

```js
var B
    ,L
    ,placeholder 
    ,correctGuesses
    ,wrongGuesses
    ,wordToGuess
    ,wordLength
    ,words=[]
    ,wrongletter=true;

    function newGame()
    {
      //initialize all the variables
      placeholder=[];  /////////initialize placeholder as an array\\\\\\\\\\\
      correctGuesses=0;
      wrongGuesses=0;
      wordToGuess=getWord();
      wordLength=wordToGuess.length;
      
      //make a loop that replaces underscores with the word to be guessed
      for(var i=0;i<wordLength;i++)
      {
       placeholder[i] = "_ ";  /////////instead of concatinating string add '_' to placeholder array\\\\\\\\\\\
      }
       document.getElementById("placeforword").innerHTML=placeholder.join("");
      
      //loop to make a keyboard of buttons 
      //B hold the buttons
     B = '';
    //L hold letters
     L;
    //this loop to get the letters by charcode
    for (var i = 65; 90 >= i; i++) {// A-65, Z-90
      L = String.fromCharCode(i);
      B += '<button id="'+L+'" onclick="getLetter(\''+L+'\');">' + L + '</button>';  /////////button id should be unique. So give each button with letter as id \\\\\\\\\\\
    }
    document.getElementById("box1").innerHTML = B;
    //drawCanvas();
    }
    function getLetter(x)
    {
       document.getElementById(x).disabled = true;  /////////disable button that clicked\\\\\\\\\\\
       checkLetter(x);
    }
    function checkLetter(letter)
    {
      wrongletter=true;
     document.getElementById("placeforword").innerHTML=placeholder;
//        placeholder=placeholder.split(""); /////////no need this since the placeholder is now an array\\\\\\\\\\\
              for(var i=0;i<wordLength;i++)
          { 
           if(wordToGuess.charAt(i)===letter.toLowerCase())
           {
               placeholder[i]=letter;
               wrongletter=false;
               correctGuesses++;
           }
           if(correctGuesses===wordLength)
           {
            //if all letters have been guessed that mean u guessed all the correct letters and u win
            //call the drawCanvas
            //drawCanvas();
    
           }
          }
           //if ur guess was wrong
     if(wrongletter)  /////////I think you mistakenly gave the variable name here\\\\\\\\\\\
     {
      wrongGuesses++;  /////////I think you mistakenly gave the variable name here\\\\\\\\\\\
      //drawCanvas();//this function to draw the body of the victim
     } 
     document.getElementById("placeforword").innerHTML=placeholder.join("");
      
    }
function getWord()
{
 var a=["bad","happy","anyotherwords"];
 //choose a random word
 return a[parseInt(Math.random()*a.length)];
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>New Game</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    #B1 {
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: white;
      font-size: 24px;
    }
    #box2 {
      width: 350px;
      height: 350px;
      padding: 10px;
      background-color: blue;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container" style="width:100%;">
    <div id="left" style="float:left;width:50%;">
      <div id="newgame">
        <button onclick="newGame()" id="B1">New Game</button>
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>
      <!--<div id="newgame1"></div>-->
      <div id="box1"></div>
      <div>
        <p id="placeforword"></p>
      </div>
      <div id="box2">
        <h1>Letters u Guessed</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="right" style="float:right;width:50%;">
      <div>
        <canvas id="stage" width="643" height="643" style="border:5px solid #000000;"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```